# How to update entire Object in Linq2SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Lets suppose I have a method like that in MVC

```
public void UpdateUser(User user)
{
  DataContext db = new DataContext();
  User u = db.Users.First(t=>t.UserId = user.UserId);
  u.Name = user.Name;
  u.LastName = user.LastName;
  db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

If we start thinking that we have properties more than Name and LastName, this process is getting cumbersome and I wonder whether there is way to easily reconcile these two objects and update it quickly.

Maybe something like this:

```
public void UpdateUser(User user)
{
  DataContext db = new DataContext();
  User u = db.Users.First(t=>t.UserId = user.UserId);
  u.MergeWith(user);
  db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

I think that would much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using(var db = new DataContext()) {
    db.Users.Attach(user, true);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

the `true` says "this object has changes, and needs to be committed".

The only downside of this is that it now doesn't know **which values** have changed, so will try to update them all. There is also an `Attach` that takes the old and new, but the old shouldn't be from the data-context you are talking to.